# TextMate can show definition of a function or a class easily?

Tags: textmate

I am using TextMate on a Ruby on Rails project and wonder if you can put the mouse on link_to, and then press a key and it will show the definition of link_to, or does this for any other helper functions or Model definition?

Or, click open a box and type in a function name and it will show you the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you are in file with
   the language grammar set to either
   Ruby or RoR (verify by checking the "L" field in TM's status bar)
2. Then highlight a function name whose
   definition you want (e.g., w/ your
   cursor just before the first letter
   of that function:
   *shift-option-right arrow*)
3. **Ctrl-H** will usually bring up a menu of two options "Ruby:
   Documentation for Selection" and
   "RoR View Demo Help", which you can
   select by pressing "1" or "2"
4. Pressing "1" will bring up the
   function's definition found in the Ruby
   Docs

Answer (score 1):

The [CTags bundle](http://gerd.knops.org/?p=7) worked really well for me when I was doing C++ in TextMate, and it should work for Ruby too (although I haven't tried it in a while).

Comment: link seems dead; this works: https://github.com/textmate/ctags.tmbundle

Answer (score 1):

**Ctrl-H** is an excellent option to learn about Ruby or Rails API.
But this doesn't work for any other methods or class that may be defined or included in your project. For those I've written a TextMate Bundle command (you can easily assign it to **Ctrl+]** for example) that lookup for the definition of the class or method under the caret and displays it in a tooltip, along with the file name and the line where it was find.

Check it out: **[Add a shortcut to TextMate to lookup a class or method definition in a tooltip](http://claudiofloreani.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-shortcut-to-textmate-to-lookup.html)**
Hope you'll find it useful ;)